# how to create .htaccess long title url

Tags: .htaccess

I am creating PHP blog viewing script I have added htaccess file to remove URL char this is my working url http://localhost/zblog/source/4/title but not working long title like this URL http://localhost/zblog/source/8/xcccxcx-cxcx-ccff single title working only

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^source/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ source.php?srcid=$1&title=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `-`char in your rule.
With `\` (or without in the end), because otherwise it's an interval.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^source/([0-9]+)/([0-9A-Z\-]+)/?$ source.php?srcid=$1&title=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: The easiest way is to redirect 301 after, from source.php